# Avoid plot/step/... output

Tags: matlab

Is there any function to avoid plot outputs of a m-file?

I mean I place a function ( like clc) on the beginning of a file and then all plot functions are blocked.

Comment: Not that I know of. But you could always run in `-nodisplay` mode, without the GUI all together.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a single command that does this, but you could accomplish with a small extra bit of code.

```
% Declare a variable for skipping at the top of your .m file
skip = 1; %example, 1 = skip, 0 = plot

% do things....

% Then nest your plot commands
if (skip == 0) % wants to plot in this case
  % Whatever plot code in here
  plot(x,y);
end
```

That should do the trick, though I realize it isn't quite a clean, single function like you requested. I hope it helps! :)

Also, I understand that if you're not necessarily working with your own .m files, or the script is very long, this may not be practical.

Answer (score 1):

You can overload the built-in plot function with your own (nested inside your function or in the same directory):

```
function myfun(a,b)
    plotting = false;
    plot(a,b);
    plot(b,a);

    function varargout = plot(varargin)
        if plotting
            [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('plot',varargin{:});
        end
    end
end
```

Nothing will happen when you call `myfun`, unless you change `plotting=false` of course.

Extra info on overloading built-in functions: http://www.mathworks.nl/support/solutions/en/data/1-18T0R/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-18T0R

Answer (score 1):

You can make *all* matlab plots invisible with:

```
set(0, 'DefaultFigureVisible', 'off');
```

Changing `off` to `on` reverses the process (which you'll probably need to do because this will switch off *all* your plots!)

You could add that line to the start of your m-file, and then add

```
close all;
set(0, 'DefaultFigureVisible', 'on');
```

to the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write `close all` after the plots, they will be plotted but instantaneously closed after. It is no clean but works.